# substitute small floats in python

Tags: python, optimization, subtraction

For an error function, I am computing the absolute error, namely `abs(should-simulated)`.

However, unfortunately, my `simulated` values can be quite small, for example 1e-38. When I try to subtract them from `should`, the output is equal to `should`, because the values are too small for Python. To prevent this, I took the logarithm of `should` and `simulated`, however, this makes the error non-linear, which does not suit my purposes. I tried using the `decimal` package, but even that doesn't work with such small numbers.
Is there any way of calculating a subtraction with small values without using the log or decimals?

Comment: So what that the error with logarithms is non-linear? Using logarithmic values is a pretty well established way of doing things. You just need to determine what relationships you want to extract.

Comment: Why is it a problem that `should-simulated` is equal to `should`, for extremely tiny values of `simulated`?  That's the most accurate answer you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decimal` package can deal with any arbitrary user-defined precision. You can get the default precision with `decimal.getcontext().prec`, and *also set this value* to get a better precision. On my machine, it is 28 by default which is not so huge but enough for most cases. You can set it to a huge value like 300 if you want a very extreme precision, but 50 should already be clearly enough. Note that a relative precision of 1e-42 is the one of an atom nucleus over the whole observable universe.